I am trying to create a table view for view/edit enrollment menu tab
I have a final due at the end of the month and i'm losing my mind creating a table view. I want it to look like the following.
enter image description here
I am getting a strange duplicate children error for a button only when view/edit enrollment is selected. Good news is, is that it still runs and everything else works. I haven't implemented any ways to catch input or display yet its still just the skeleton.
https://onlinegdb.com/ZXsegAPs7
This is my main code along with the required Student.java, Course.java, Enrollment.java classes seperate.
Thank you!
When pressing Enrollments -> View/Edit Enrollment I get the following message.
Note: Main.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Prism ES2 Error - nInitialize: glXChooseFBConfig failed
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = ButtonBarSkin$1@77240d5a[styleClass=container]
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.Parent$3.onProposedChange(Parent.java:561)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.add(VetoableListDecorator.java:205)
    at javafx.controls@18.0.2/javafx.scene.control.skin.ButtonBarSkin.doButtonOrderLayout(ButtonBarSkin.java:205)
    at javafx.controls@18.0.2/javafx.scene.control.skin.ButtonBarSkin.layoutButtons(ButtonBarSkin.java:174)
    at javafx.controls@18.0.2/javafx.scene.control.skin.ButtonBarSkin.<init>(ButtonBarSkin.java:108)
    at javafx.controls@18.0.2/javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar.createDefaultSkin(ButtonBar.java:503)
    at javafx.controls@18.0.2/javafx.scene.control.Control.doProcessCSS(Control.java:899)
    at javafx.controls@18.0.2/javafx.scene.control.Control$1.doProcessCSS(Control.java:89)
    at javafx.controls@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.processCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:67)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:146)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1400)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:146)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9477)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Scene.java:572)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Scene.java:1770)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.Scene$2.preferredSize(Scene.java:396)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.scene.SceneHelper.preferredSize(SceneHelper.java:66)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.stage.Window$12.invalidated(Window.java:1163)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:1239)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:1254)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:277)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.stage.Stage.showAndWait(Stage.java:467)
    at javafx.controls@18.0.2/javafx.scene.control.HeavyweightDialog.showAndWait(HeavyweightDialog.java:162)
    at javafx.controls@18.0.2/javafx.scene.control.Dialog.showAndWait(Dialog.java:346)
    at Main.editEnrollmentItem(Main.java:632)
    at Main.lambda$start$17(Main.java:126)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.controls@18.0.2/javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:459)
    at javafx.controls@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1385)
    at javafx.controls@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$12(ContextMenuContent.java:1338)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3881)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1874)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2607)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:316)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)


Please don't link to your code. You should create a [mre] demonstrating the problem and put that example in your question as code-formatted text. See the previously-linked page and the [help] (in particular [ask]) for more information.

That all said, each Alert you're creating has a default set of button types based on the AlertType. You then add your own button types to the alert's dialog pane, at least some of which were already present. And DialogPane keeps a map of button type to node, so duplicate button types results in the same node being added to the scene graph, thus the error. You can fix this by passing the button types during construction or by using setAll instead of addAll.

Try changing dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(okButtonType, ButtonType.CANCEL); to dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().setAll(okButtonType, ButtonType.CANCEL); in the following code.
dialog.setTitle("View/Edit Enrollment");
dialog.setHeaderText(null);
dialog.setContentText("Please select an action:");

// Create the grid for dialog content
GridPane grid = new GridPane();
grid.setHgap(10);
grid.setVgap(10);
grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 150, 10, 10));

// Add content to the grid if needed

// Add buttons to the dialog
ButtonType okButtonType = new ButtonType("ADD", ButtonBar.ButtonData.OK_DONE);
dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().setAll(okButtonType, ButtonType.CANCEL);
dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(grid);

// Show and wait for user input
Optional<ButtonType> result = dialog.showAndWait();
if (result.isPresent() && result.get() == okButtonType){
    // Add the new course to the database or perform any other necessary action
    // ...
}

